# How to undo a `declaration` proclamation?

Tags: common-lisp

It appears that most (if not all) global [declarations](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_c.htm) cannot be reverted in an ANSI CL standard way.

E.g., once you evaluate (either directly or by loading a file) a form like `(proclaim '(declaration my-decl))` or `(declaim (special *my-var*))` there is no *portable* way to make `(declare (my-decl ...))` illegal or `*my-var*` lexical.

Various implementation offer non-portable way to revert the [`special`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_specia.htm) declaration, usually via `(proclaim '(notspecial *my-var*))` or some other trick.

**How about the [`declaration`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_declar.htm) [proclamation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#proclamation)?**

How do various implementations undo it?
How would you implement it?
Do you think `(proclaim '(notdeclaration my-decl))` is a good idea?

**Motivation**: in a test suite, it would be nice to be modular - to be able to revert all effects of a test statements to avoid any possible interference with test suite parts. I know it's a week motivation because The Right Way is to use [packages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_.htm).

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you unintern the symbol for the variable? This would probably be a bad idea as it will mess up any boundary between old/new references to the symbol

Comment: I don't see any proper way to do it in SBCL, but it seems like `(setf (sb-int:info :declaration :recognized name-of-the-declaration) nil)` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to provide a transaction mechanism (rollback/commit). This is taken from Xach's Naggum's [archive](http://www.xach.com/naggum/articles/3248373467280622@naggum.no.html):

> I miss a transaction facility where I can make a number of changes
>   to the system that are only visible to my thread of a multi-threaded
>   execution environment and then discard them or commit them all at
>   once.  E.g., loading a file could be such a transcation.  Signaling
>   an error during loading could cause the whole slew of operations
>   that preceded it to be discarded instead of leaving the system in a
>   partially modified state.  This is not impossible to build on top of
>   the existing system, but it takes significant effort, so it is the
>   kind of thing that Common Lisp systems programmers should do.

You would miss the possibility to undo only a subset of the declarations, like `(declare A)`, `(declare B)`, `(undeclare A)` but given your motivation, it would not be a problem because you are likely to want to undo all possible declarations made during a test.

You could provide a special form to individually "undeclare" declarations. I'd name it **retract**, but this might be difficult to specify in some cases. Suppose you declare that x is either a string or a number, can you retract a declaration that says x is a string? What about inline functions, etc? A transaction looks easier to implement, with e.g. a temporary environment.

Comment: I was asking about a syntax that would exposed the mechanism, but the transaction approach is, indeed, interesting.

Comment: @sds For the syntax, I would rather have `(declaim (not X))` with X any valid declaration expression than different `notdeclaration` symbol for each valid `declaration`. Also, `not` might be confusing: `(declare (not (type T X)))` is generally not the same as `(declare (type (not T) X))`. Prolog has `assert` and `retract` built-ins, maybe `(retract declaration)` would be better.